# yarn upgrade to fix yarn audit errors

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, yarnpkg, npm-audit

So, as of now, it appears that there is no `yarn audit --fix`, so I am trying to figure out how to go about fixing my `yarn audit` errors.

I have tried a `yarn upgrade` which has fixed some of the errors (which is great), but there are still several remaining.

I then tried a `yarn add <package>@latest` for the remaining high vulnerabilities, but it upgrades the version in my `package.json`, when I think the issue is coming from a dependency of a package that I am using.

Here is an example of some of my remaining errors:

```
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ high          │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ minimatch                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ gulp                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ gulp > vinyl-fs > glob-stream > glob > minimatch             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/118                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ high          │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ minimatch                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ gulp                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ gulp > vinyl-fs > glob-stream > minimatch                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/118                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ high          │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ minimatch                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ gulp                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ gulp > vinyl-fs > glob-watcher > gaze > globule > glob >     │
│               │ minimatch                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/118                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ high          │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ minimatch                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.2                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ gulp                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ gulp > vinyl-fs > glob-watcher > gaze > globule > minimatch  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/118                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ moderate      │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ lodash                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=4.17.11                                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ gulp                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ gulp > vinyl-fs > glob-watcher > gaze > globule > lodash     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/782                       │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The solution to this problem in yarn is called [selective version resolutions](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) which is basically defining `resolutions` for the transitive dependencies in the `package.json`.

The `transitive dependencies` are the dependencies of dependencies.

```
{
   "resolutions": { "**/**/lodash": "^4.17.12" }
}
```

So here even if the lodash isn't a direct dependency of your package, the dependent package in your package uses the version defined in the resolutions. Specific resolutions can also be provided. More info [here](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/).

Answer (score 17):

While `resolutions` work, it is not the optimal solution, because:

- you clutter your `package.json` with resolutions of transitive dependencies
- you override the *actually required version* with *what you think will work version*. Assume `A` depends on `B@^4.0.0` and you update B and resolve it to `^4.3.2`. Some time later A gets an update and requires `B@^5.0.0`, but you still resolve B to `^4.3.2`, which is not compatible anymore.

**Here is another way to update transitive dependencies:**

1. delete the version of the dependency you want to update from `yarn.lock`
2. run `yarn install`

This way you force yarn to resolve the dependency again and in most cases yarn will install a newer version of what you deleted from `yarn.lock`.

**Example**: let's assume that you want to update vulnerable `minimist@0.0.8`, then you need to delete an entry like this from your `yarn.lock`:

```
minimist@0.0.8:
  version "0.0.8"
  resolved "http://10.0.0.1/repository/npm-registry/minimist/-/minimist-0.0.8.tgz#857fcabfc3397d2625b8228262e86aa7a011b05d"
  integrity sha1-hX/Kv8M5fSYluCKCYuhqp6ARsF0=
```

and then run `yarn install`.

**If this doesn't help:**

Try updating dependencies that are higher in the dependency chain:

1. Run `yarn why <dependency>` to find out which packages pull it
2. Go up the chain and try deleting the upper dependency in the chain from `yarn.lock` and then running `yarn install`

**Example:**

Here is an example, where we update a transitive dependency `minimist`:

```
$ yarn why minimist
.....
=> Found "mkdirp#minimist@0.0.8"
info This module exists because "eslint#mkdirp" depends on it.
=> Found "optimist#minimist@0.0.10"
info This module exists because "jest#jest-cli#@jest#core#@jest#reporters#istanbul-reports#handlebars#optimist" depends on it.
.....
```

1. Delete `minimist` entries from yarn.lock and run `yarn install` -> this doesn't help, presumably because `mkdirp` and `optimist` require exactly `minimist@0.0.8` and `minimist@0.0.10`
2. Delete "direct parents" of `minimist` from yarn.lock: `mkdirp` and `optimist`.
3. Run `yarn install`.
4. Run `yarn why minimist` again:

   ```
   $ yarn why minimist
   .....
   => Found "mkdirp#minimist@1.2.5"
   info This module exists because "eslint#mkdirp" depends on it.
   => Found "optimist#minimist@0.0.10"
   info This module exists because "jest#jest-cli#@jest#core#@jest#reporters#istanbul-reports#handlebars#optimist" depends on it.
   .....
   ```

   Here we see that `minimist@0.0.8` was updated to `minimist@1.2.5`, but `minimist@0.0.10` still exists.
5. Delete the next dependency in the dependency chain from `yarn.lock`: `handlebars`
6. Run `yarn install`
7. Run `yarn why minimist` - nothing changed, `minimist@0.0.10` is still there.
8. Delete the next dependency in the chain from `yarn.lock`: `istanbul-reports`
9. Run `yarn install`
10. Run `yarn why minimist`: `minimist@0.0.10` is not there anymore, because `istanbul-reports` was updated.

Comment: Manual editing of `yarn.lock` is not recommended. Couldn't we reach the same simply removing the topmost library and adding it again?

Comment: Manual editing of `yarn.lock` is kind of the last resort. You should just delete `yarn.lock` and run `yarn install` to generate a new one. That will update all dependencies according to your `package.json`. If such an update breaks your project, then versions selectors in your `package.json` do not really reflect your dependency requirements, and you should fix that.

Comment: Manual editing of yarn.lock is iffy, but just delete the whole thing, and node_modules and yarn again... should do the same, albeit take much longer...